# iOS App's Application Support Directory files access when app is in AppStore

Tags: ios

**Question:** For an iOS App in AppStore, can anyone access `applicationSupportDirectory` after downloading it to device?

**Discussion:** Actually, I am putting some important files in the directory programmatically when they are downloaded from a server, and I wish no softwares like `iExlorer` or hackers can see those files even phone goes jail broken.
Your positive input would be helpful for me to secure the files.

**Note:** Before down-voting the question, do ask yourself if you can improve the question more, if yes please do.

Comment: Just try it yourself on an existing app. Obviously on jailbroken devices any data is accessible.

Comment: If you are really afraid of someone getting you data, you might want to encrypt the downloaded data. This way you will make it more difficult to user to get the data.

Comment: @Chanchal Raj, the news has reported this , FBI can access iPhone's data.

Comment: @jcaron, previously iExplorer could be used for looking at Documents folder, but now iOS has made it more secure causing iExplorer to not see things. What other ways can there be to test exploitations?